# MegaRaid Storage Manager - lack of option "Create Virtual Drive"

Tags: raid, megaraid, megaraid-storage-manager

I'm using MegaRaid Storage Manager v 14.11.01.00
I want to create second Virtual Drive.
I see

- Scan Foreing Configuration
- Save Configuration
- Clear Configuration
- Preserved Cache (greyed)
- Update Controller Firmware

In the documentation I see that there should be "Create Virtual Drive" at the top of options list.

But I do not have such option.

My question is:

Why I do not have option "Create Virtual Drive" ?

Thank you in advance,
mLipok

[Screenshot from MegaRAID Storage Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOZKJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why can't you use direct RAID card configuration while booting server ?

Secondly, if you want to use MSM instead try to scan drives ([Scan Foreing Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19203-01/820-4933-15/msmir.html#0_48079)) and then you should see your new discovered drives.

If you still can't see new drives, probably your RAID card is not supported, so provide us more information about your system.

Comment: In OP I attach screnshot. This is already after scan. Still is missing option for create .

Comment: `Firstly, why can't you use direct RAID card configuration while booting server ?` I work from distant. There was added drive by my colegue, but we do not want restart server as we need to create additional backup first..... which will take extra time etc...

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me.

I've added new disks, and I don't see the "Create Virtual Drive" option.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573380)